# How to override a macro in dbt-external-tables package for dbt in the project?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jinja2, dbt

I want to override the function `create_empty_table`[here](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-external-tables/blob/main/macros/plugins/snowflake/snowpipe/create_empty_table.sql) in the `dbt-external-tables` [package](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-external-tables) that we use to create Snowpipes for Snowflake.

I have tried defining my new macro in multiple ways including just defining it as `create_empty_table`, as it is defined in the package `snowflake_create_empty_table` as well as `snowflake__create_empty_table` as the macro functionality is only needed for snowflake. I have also tried adding this portion as defined in the dbt docs here.

```
dispatch:
  - macro_namespace: dbt-external-tables
    search_order: ['project-name', 'dbt-external-tables']
```

This is an example from dbt's github [issue](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-external-tables/issues/140) that I am trying to implement.

```
{% macro snowflake_create_empty_table(source_node) %}

    {%- set columns = source_node.columns.values() %}

    create or replace table {{source(source_node.source_name, source_node.name)}} (
        {%- for column in columns %}
            {%- set column_quoted = adapter.quote(column.name) if column.quote else column.name %}
            {%- set col_expression -%}
                {%- if column.col_expression -%}
                    {{column.col_expression}}
                {%- else -%}
                    {%- set col_id = 'value:c' ~ loop.index if is_csv else 'value:' ~ column_quoted -%}
                    (case when is_null_value({{col_id}}) or lower({{col_id}}) = 'null' then null else {{col_id}} end)
                {%- endif -%}
            {%- endset %}
            {{column_quoted}} {{column.data_type}} as ({{col_expression}}::{{column.data_type}})
            {{- ',' if not loop.last -}}
        {% endfor %}
        current_timestamp::timestamp as _dbt_copied_at

    );

{% endmacro %}
```

But I can't seem to get it to work. Does anybody have tried this or have any thoughts on how to get it working?

Comment: What errors are you seeing? Why do you say it is not working?

Comment: My overridden macro is not being used because I added a column that should show up in the table in snowflake but it doesn't.